# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto generate wrong data type in table for id

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i have tables; users, user_roles.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", 
    uniqueConstraints = { 
      @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
      @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") 
    })
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(max = 20)
  private String username;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(max = 50)
  @Email
  private String email;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(max = 120)
  private String password;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(  name = "user_roles", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(length = 20)
  private ERole name;

  public Role() {

  }
```

**user_roles table**

| user_id | role_id |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

```
 users table
```

| id | email | password | username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

i have exceptions when i run the project

```
foreign key constraint "fkhfh9dx7w3ubf1co1vdev94g3f" cannot be implemented
  Detail: Key columns "user_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: bigint and character varying.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:329) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:286) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
```

is there the bug(s) spring data jpa, I'm thinking of this.

To solve this issue, I dropped the tables and let Hibernate recreate them, and now the error is gone. However, I'm still wondering why the "id" column was created as "character varying" in the first place, which caused the foreign key constraint issue. Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: Can you provide `Role` class java code? Also provide what data type it uses on database for user's user_id, role's role_id, user_roles user_id/role_id?

Comment: i have edited, i didn't choose data types, hibernate created them.

Comment: Change Role id datatype to Long instead of Integer. To make it consistent with id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in stacktrace: `Detail: Key columns "user_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: bigint and character varying.`. You have mismatch of types it means you need to change types of your variables to bigInt in database, because seems that you have variable with type varchar or text.
You could modify the "user_id" column to be of type `bigint` in the database.
After this change, you should be able to recreate the tables.

Comment: Yes, I tried modifying the data type of the "user_id" column in the "user_roles" table as you suggested, but now I'm getting a different error: "null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint". It's strange because I didn't set the "id" column to null.